# How to read data from Firebase in kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with my quizz app. My all questions and answers include in class in app. I wanna change it and upload my json to firebase, but i have problem with reading it. What i do wrong?

[**My Database in Firebase**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6e2a.png)

I learn with Log read data. This is my code:

```
 val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Question")

    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("Response", error.message)

        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
           for (ds in snapshot.children) {
               Log.d("Response", reference.toString())
           }
        }
    })
```

[**My Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unJt8.png)

I wanna reading all data from my firebase and setup in ui

**Thanks for tips and help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to log a DatabaseReference object as you are here:

```
Log.d("Response", reference.toString())
```

The data you're looking for is in the `snapshot` argument you received in the callback.  Log the contents of that instead:

```
Log.d("Response", ds.getValue())
```